# ReactJS, useEffect without depts vs const

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I've just see this code:

```
const defaultState = { // some object };

const SomeComponent = ({
  complete
}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);
  const {
    color,
    icon
  } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (complete) {
      setState({
        ...state,
        color: '#61a60e',
      });
    } else {
      setState({
        ...state,
        color: 'red',
      });
    }
  }, []);

 // etc
```

I wonder, is that really necesary that `useEffect`?

The `if` statement inside the `useEffect` has a control value that comes as prop on the componente (complete), so in my opinion that code would be the same than this:

```
const defaultState = { // some object };

const SomeComponent = ({
  complete
}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);
  const {
    color,
    icon
  } = state;

  setState({
    ...state,
    color: complete ? '#61a60e' : 'red'
  });
```

I'm ok? Or there's something about `useEffect` that I'm not considering.

Comment: Did you try to run the 2nd approach? Didn't it make an infinite rerender?

Comment: I havne't, just seen the code, but now I get the idea of the useEffect with empty [], it will render once, so I think it's ok

Comment: `setState`, directly in a render (2nd example), will cause infinite rerender. Because it will set the state at every render. So, `setState` is always (mostly) used in an event handler like `onClick` or an effect hook (with some proper dependencies).

Comment: As you have already found out the useEffect with an empty deps array will only run once - on the first render. And what does it do? it evaluates some prop value to set the state. Therefore it can be simplified to `const [state, setState] = useState({
    ...defaultState,
    color: complete ? '#61a60e' : 'red'
  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You need to understand about useEffect: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

In your example, `useEffect` was call without dependencies. So it likes `componentDidMout` and only calls one time. Base on the `complete` props. It will update `color` for state. It works fine.

About your update without `useEffect`. `setState` call directly in the component. So every component render (state or props change). The `setState` will be called => state change => component render => ... => infinite rerender. It's terrible. Never do that.

Note: If you use `setState` in `useEffect`, you need to add `[dependencies]` to avoid infinite loops. `dependencies` maybe have value or not(like example above). Make sure you understand `dependencies` in `useEffect` before using it.

Comment: But the Note is =><= with what you said first, so I won't necesary add deps even with those setState there

Comment: Yes. I mean we must add `[]`. It can have dependencies or not (read the article with you want to add dependencies). But if you don't have `[]`. It'll infinite loops